# When running from systemd unit file, unable to open directory

Tags: systemd

I have a strange problem with Ubuntu 16 and a systemd unit file. I have a service which reads a directory from the local filesystem. The directory is read from an environment variable. Now when I start the service manually (as in: in a ssh session), everything works fine. But when I start the service with the unit file from below, the service is unable to open the `storage` directory. The error I get is: `could nog read contents of storage" message="open /srv/services/poddy/storage: no such file or directory`.

Now my question is: does systemd kind of "sandbox" the services?

```
[Unit]
Description=Poddy service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=myusername
Group=myusername
WorkingDirectory=/srv/services/poddy
ExecStart=/srv/services/poddy/poddy
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
StartLimitInterval=60s
StartLimitBurst=3
Environment=PODDY_STORAGE="/srv/services/poddy/storage"
Environment=PODDY_PORT=8085

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved it myself. It turns out that quoting the value of an environment var in the systemd unit file eventually double-escaped the value.

So, changing this:

```
Environment=PODDY_STORAGE="/srv/services/poddy/storage"
```

into:

```
Environment=PODDY_STORAGE=/srv/services/poddy/storage
```

solved my problem :).